# Recreate AVCHD structure / CPI files from MTS

Tags: video, camera, video-processing, video-encoding, video-editing

Yet another question on AVCHD. I've been looking for this for a while now without finding a solution.
I've got M2TS files from a Lumix cam. I want to re-create the AVCHD structure where they came from.

- I can play the M2TS files with VLC, so they are OK
- The AVCHD file structure is documented and I am able to create the folder structure. I can also use one generated by the cam itself...
- However, I didn't find a way to recreate the CPI files associated with each and every M2TS file. I understand these files contain basic metadata about the M2TS but didn't find a tool to recreate them. I tried tools that say they can create the AVCHD structure but when I try to import the M2TS file, they mention that they also need the CPI Files.
- I've tried softs such as CLIPINF Editor of Bdedit or clipwrap or even VSO AVCHD editor but none recreate the CLI files.
- I've tried to create videos with my cam with the same length and then replace the created video with the M2TS file I have but it doesn't work.
- I don't want to recode/transcode/export anything. I just would like to create the structure in my SD Card, copy the M2TS files and the associated CPI files on it, insert it in the cam and have the cam read them.

Does anyone know how to do that or maybe why it can't be done.
Many thanks.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with Panasonic's [AVCCAM Restorer](https://eww.pass.panasonic.co.jp/pro-av/support/dload/avccam_restorer/agree_e.htm), which has both Mac & Windows versions.

It will allow you to regenerate the AVCHD structure either on an external drive (e.g. SD card) or from a folder of .MTS files. Whether it's sufficient will probably depend on your intended usage, but I've found iMovie '11 (10.0.6) is able to read the `BDMV` container within the folder structure as a proper clip. I haven't tried it yet on an SD card.